# Why when using useState() do multiple entries get displayed in the console when I console.log the current state?

Tags: react-hooks

Why does currentCount display 4 entries in the console instead of one and clicking the button I get 3 entries in the console instead of one?

```js
**strong text**strong text

import React, { useState } from "react";

const Counter = () => {
  let [currentCount, setCurrentCount] = useState(0); 
  console.log(currentCount); // logs 4 entries in the console on page reload 

function handleClick() {
    setCurrentCount(currentCount + 1);
   console.log(currentCount);   // logs 2 entries in the console when button is clicked
 }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>+1</button>
      <div>{currentCount}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Counter;
```

Comment: *"logs 2 entries in the console when button is clicked"* - How have you debugged to confirm that this specific line of code is being executed twice.  If you're seeing two entries in the console when clicking the button, that would be due to having **two** `console.log` statements.  One in the click handler, and one in the component body that executes in every render.

Comment: That's just it.  Even though I have one console.log in the body it logs 2 identical entries to the console. Also, regardless if I don't have a console.log in the handleClick function duplicate entries are logged to the console and I have no idea why.

Comment: Who would have guessed that using <React.StrictMode> in root.render would cause duplicate entries to be logged to the console. Finally able to decipher the issue.